# List all container images in a kustomization or yaml manifest list?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

When operating a k8s cluster with an admission controller that limits the allowed registries, it's desirable to check manifests to verify they only refer to such images.

Is there a well established and correct way to process a Kubernetes manifest stream such as Kustomize output and list all container images it references? Including all `Deployment`s, `StatefulSet`s, `Job`s, CRDs that embed `PodTemplate`, etc?

I landed up writing my own, then realised this *must* be a solved problem. `kustomize` has the `images:` transformer to *rewrite* images, but it doesn't seem to be able to *list* the candidates the transformer inspects. Surely there's something?

For example, if I have the `kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - "https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus"
```

I want to be able to run some `getimages` filter such that

```
kustomize build | getimages
```

returns the same list as this hacky shell pipeline example:

```
$ kustomize build|grep 'image:' | awk '$2 != "" { print $2}' | sort -u
grafana/grafana:8.4.6
jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.5.0
k8s.gcr.io/kube-state-metrics/kube-state-metrics:v2.4.2
k8s.gcr.io/prometheus-adapter/prometheus-adapter:v0.9.1
quay.io/brancz/kube-rbac-proxy:v0.12.0
quay.io/prometheus/alertmanager:v0.24.0
quay.io/prometheus/blackbox-exporter:v0.20.0
quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter:v1.3.1
quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator:v0.55.1
quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.34.0
```

... but in a robust and correct manner, unlike said hacky shell command.

I expected tools like `kubeval` or `kustomize` to be able to do this, but have drawn blanks in all searching.

---

Edit: There *is* `kustomize cfg tree --image` to list images, but:

- It doesn't integrate with [the kustomize image transformer's configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71920861/398670) so it won't recognise images in CRDs. You have to add additional `--field` specs for each one manually.
- Its output format is painful if you just want the image names.

Comment: I landed up writing a Python script that loads the yaml stream and uses some matching rules to extract images. But that's crazy to have to do when Kustomize already knows how to do this (mostly).