# Extend kustomize image transformer for new types

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

**Is there a way to extend the kustomize image transformer to recognise more keys as image specifiers?** Like the [`nameReference` transformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#name-reference-transformer) does for the `namePrefix` and `nameSuffix` transformers.

[The Kustomize `images:` transformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md) is very useful for image replacement and registry renaming in k8s manifests.

But it [only supports types that embed `PodTemplate`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/686) and maybe some hardcoded types. CRDs that don't use `PodTemplate` are not handled despite them being *very* common. Examples include the `kube-prometheus` `Prometheus` and `AlertManager` resources and the `opentelemetry-operator` `OpenTelemetryCollector` resource.

As a result you land up having to maintain a bunch of messy strategic merge or json patches to prefix such images with a trusted registry or the like.

---

Here's an example of the problem as things stand. Say I have to deploy everything prefixed with `mytrusted.registry` with an `images:` transformer list. For the sake of brevity here I'll use a dummy one that replaces all matched images with `MATCHED`, so I don't have to list them all:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - "https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus"
images:
  - name: "(.*)"
    newName: "MATCHED"
    newTag: "fake"
```

You'd expect the only images in the result to be "MATCHED:fake", but in reality:

```
$ kustomize build  | grep 'image: .*' | sort | uniq -c
     12         image: MATCHED:fake
      1   image: quay.io/prometheus/alertmanager:v0.24.0
      1   image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.34.0
```

the images in the `kind: Prometheus` and `kind: AlertManager` resources don't get matched because they are not a `PodTemplate`.

You have to write a custom patch for these, which creates mess like this `kustomization.yaml` content:

```
patches:
  - path: prometheus_image.yaml
    target:
      kind: Prometheus
  - path: alertmanager_image.yaml
    target:
      kind: Alertmanager
```

with `prometheus_image.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
      name: ignored
spec:
      image: "MATCHED:fake"
```

and `alertmanager_image.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Alertmanager
metadata:
      name: ignored
spec:
      image: "MATCHED:fake"
```

which is IMO ghastly.

What I *want* to be able to do is tell `Kustomize`'s image transformer about it, like it can be extended with custom configmap generators, etc, like the following *unsupported and imaginary pseudocode* modeled on the existing [`nameReference` transformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#name-reference-transformer)

```
imageReference:
  - kind: Prometheus
    fieldSpecs:
      - spec/image
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just after writing this up I finally stumbled on the answer: Kustomize does support [image transformer configs](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/images/README.md).

The correct way to express the above would be a `image_transformer_config.yaml` file containing:

```
images:
  - path: spec/image
    kind: Prometheus
  - path: spec/image
    kind: Alertmanager
```

and a `kustomization.yaml` entry referencing it, like

```
configurations:
  - image_transformer_config.yaml
```

This appears to work fine when imported as a `Component` too.

It's even [pointed out by the transformer docs](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#images-transformer) so I'm going to blame this one on being blind.